# Snakes, Ladders and Magic Dice

Tags: logical-deduction

This is a great Puzzle recently I made.

A Wizard has captured 2 friends A and B in a Magical land with Snakes and Ladders in different rooms. There are a total of 100 rooms. The Wizard gives both of them Magical Dice each by which they can throw any number they wish for. They can escape the land if they follow the rules below.

Rules:

**• The Magic Dice will roll any number from 1-6. For example, if person A throws the dice with the wish of number 3, so 3 will come, and person A will move to position 3.**

**• If you finish a room that contains the bottom of a ladder, you must climb to the top of the ladder.**

**• If you finish a room that contains the head of a snake, you must move to the bottom of the snake’s tail.**

**• When a snake or a ladder is used by any person, it immediately disappears so you can't use it again.**

•   **Both of the friends must reach the 100th room in six or fewer moves each to exit. First-person A has to do his all moves to reach the 100th position and then person B has to reach there after all of his moves to escape.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Person A

> - Roll a 6. Reaches room 6.
> - Roll a 1. Take the ladder at 7 to reach 38.
> - Roll a 6 to reach 44.
> - Roll a 6 to reach 50. The snake pushes you down to 17.
> - Roll a 5 to reach 22. The snake pushes you down to 4.
> - Roll a 6. The ladder at 10 takes you directly to 100.

Person B

> - Roll a 5 to reach 16.
> - Roll a 6 to reach 22. No snake because previous person stepped on it.
> - Roll a 6 again to reach 28, the ladder takes you to 44.
> - Roll a 6 again to reach 50. No snake for the same reason.
> - Roll a 6 to reach 56. The ladder takes you to 98.
> - Now roll a 2 to get to 100.

Reasoning

> The ladder at 10 is the fastest way to reach 100 so it makes sense that at least one person should be using that ladder. But then there is no other way to make another person reach 100 within 6 steps unless we make some of the snakes disappear. From there on it is easy to figure out.